# VBA - Creating a Data Sheet from a User Form

Tags: vba, button

I'm hoping that someone can help me with my issue. I've searched this site for the correct coding for my spreadsheets, but nothing seems to work.

I have two spreadsheets: I have a front facing form (Sheet1) where the user can input information. Once the user is done inputting their information, they will press a button which will transfer the data to a large data spreadsheet ("Records"). Once the data copies from Sheet1 to Records, I want Sheet1 to clear (so that the next user has a blank form to work from). Additionally, when a new user inputs information, I want that information to go on a line below the previous user's data input on Records.

I hope that this makes sense... This is the code that I'm using now, which doesn't populate anything in "Records" (I've clearly made a mess of this).

```
Sub BUTTON()
Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant
refTable = Array("c = e6", "d = e7", "e=e8", "f=e9", "g=e10")
Dim Row As Long
Row = Worksheets("Records").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
For Each trans In refTable
    Dim Dest As String, Field As String
    Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & Row
    Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))
Next

End Sub
```

Does anyone have any advice for coding? Please let me know!

Comment: What are the values in the array e.g. `"c = e6"`?

Comment: For that example: "C" would be the receiving column in Records. "E6" is the cell location in the form that the user would input first. In other words, "E6" in Sheet1 theoretically would be transferred to column "C" once the button is pushed. The same goes for the other values: "E7", the next cell that the user can fill in, corresponds to column D in the Records sheet.

Comment: Are there just five fields on the form (as in your example) or are there more?

Comment: Hi Alex, the user fills out 20 fields on the form (Sheet1) which correspond to 20 columns in Records (so column A through V). Do you need the exact fields for Sheet1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

The key bit is to set up the `fields` as per the order you want them to appear in `worksheets("Records")` in columns `A to V`.

For example, in my example `e6` maps to column `A`, `e7` to column `B` etc.

```
Sub MapInputToColumn()
    Dim fields As Range, rw As Integer, col As Integer

    Set fields = Union(Range("e6"), Range("e7"), Range("e8"), Range("e9"), Range("e10"))
    rw = Worksheets("Records").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    For col = 1 To fields.Count
        Worksheets("Records").Cells(rw, col) = fields(col, 1)
    Next col

    fields.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for your code! It clears the Sheet1 when I click the button but then does not update the records sheet... any advice?

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried debugging on the `for....next` loop to check the values of rw and col etc? It worked for me when I tested it

Comment: Sub Copy()
Dim fields As Range, rw As Integer, col As Integer

    Set fields = Union(Range("D6:D9"), Range("F6:F10"), Range("D15:D18"), Range("F15:F16"), Range("C22:F26"), Range("C31:F35"), Range("C39:F43"), Range("D45:D46"))
    
    rw = Worksheets("Records").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    For col = 1 To fields.Count
        Worksheets("Records").Cells(rw, col) = fields(col, 1)
    Next col

    fields.ClearContents
End Sub